# Stop filter from applying on grid if condition matched in filterModified event

Tags: angular, typescript, types, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am Using AG-Grid in my project
i am listening my filter modification event through the  (filterModified).
here is my code where i am calling ag-grid in html

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <ag-grid-angular
      class="ag-theme-bootstrap"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [modules]="modules"
      [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      [headerHeight]="null"
      (cellValueChanged) = updateCellData($event)
      (cellDoubleClicked) = setColumnWidth($event)
      (filterModified)="filterMod($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
```

i am able to detect the filterModified.
i have event valur in filterMod

```js
filterMod(ev) {
    if (this._gridDataArr.length >= 1) {
      console.log(ev);
      // how can i stop filter to be applied in grid data if 
      // gridDataArr length is greater than 1 
    }
  }

I tried to find some solution in documentation but no Luck
I also tried using GridApi with setfilterModel() but i think i am not using it correctly.
```

Answer (score 2):

`PreventDefault` is the best solution to stop propagating event bubble to its parent from child control. but here the problem is that `filtermodified` event doesn't give you $event in `params`.

Still you can do it, no need to write custom filter you can set the filter model to null. although this is not good user experience as an end-user I might feel puzzled that my filters are getting reverted as soon as I am typing them. Better to inform end-user with some `toast/growl` message to let them know why the filter is getting reset.

```
    gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: columnDefs,
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 150,
        filter: true,
        sortable: true,
      },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ,onFilterModified : function(params){
    if (this._gridDataArr.length >= 1) {
    //set the filter to none if your condition is true.
    params.api.setFilterModel(null);
    }
    } 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create your own custom filter component. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-component).

The main method one want to utilise is `isFilterActive`, where you'll return false if `this._gridDataArr.length >= 1`.

Comment: i don't want to create my own custom filter. I Only want to confirm with user via a confirm box if they will apply the filter they will loose the some inline changes that are stored in gridDataArr

Comment: yep, you'll need a custom filter to do that.

Comment: So there is not any way available in AG grid by which i can stop grid filtering. After filter change.